CPU does not scale down at high temperatures and overheats
I have a Thinkpad T430 with an i7-3520M CPU. This is rated to run at 2.90GHz, but it can boost up to 3.5GHz.
Previously I would use Windows 10. It is an old laptop, and CPU temperatures can get quite high, but on Windows it would never heat up to the point where it would shut off on me. It would instead stop boosting and lower the clock speed to compensate for the high heat, if I remember correctly. When the laptop is docked, due to the less ideal cooling setup it would heat up faster, but it would still not overheat on Windows 10.
When I'm using Kubuntu 24.04 (kernel 6.8.0-51), I noticed that the CPU can reach very high temperatures of around 95C during high CPU usage. The clock rate also seems to be constantly boosting to 3.5GHz, despite the high temperatures. At high temperatures, I noticed in top that there are some processes called "idle_inject" that have a high CPU usage. After googling those, it seems that the kernel uses these processes to inject idle wait states to force the CPU to idle to cool down, if I understand correctly. However, it doesnt seem like it's doing anything to help, and the CPU clock stays at 3.5GHz.
On prolonged workloads, the laptop would eventually force shutdown. I feel that this isn't normal behaviour and there is something wrong with the way the kernel is managing the CPU frequency. What can I do?
Note: I realize that I could do hardware fixes like cleaning/replacing the fan, replacing the thermal paste, etc. But the fact is that the CPU is boosting when it shouldn't be, and I believe this is controlled in software, and didn't happen on Windows. So there should be a way to fix it.
EDIT:
Here are some thermald logs
Dec 30 09:08:47 the9a3eedi-linux thermald[1475]: 13 CPUID levels; family:model:stepping 0x6:3a:9 (6:58:9)
Dec 30 09:08:47 the9a3eedi-linux thermald[1475]: 13 CPUID levels; family:model:stepping 0x6:3a:9 (6:58:9)
Dec 30 09:08:49 the9a3eedi-linux thermald[1475]: sensor id 4 : No temp sysfs for reading raw temp
Dec 30 09:08:49 the9a3eedi-linux thermald[1475]: sensor id 4 : No temp sysfs for reading raw temp
Dec 30 09:08:49 the9a3eedi-linux thermald[1475]: sensor id 4 : No temp sysfs for reading raw temp
Dec 30 09:08:49 the9a3eedi-linux thermald[1475]: Config file /etc/thermald/thermal-conf.xml does not exist
Dec 30 09:08:49 the9a3eedi-linux thermald[1475]: Config file /etc/thermald/thermal-conf.xml does not exist
Dec 30 09:08:49 the9a3eedi-linux thermald[1475]: Config file /etc/thermald/thermal-conf.xml does not exist
Dec 30 09:08:49 the9a3eedi-linux thermald[1475]: Polling mode is enabled: 4
Dec 30 09:08:49 the9a3eedi-linux systemd[1]: Started thermald.service - Thermal Daemon Service.
    


I may simply be that your machine is simply underpowered on the CPU side for running Kubuntu, especially as KDE is one of the more demanding desktop environments. If you want to stay within the Ubuntu universe, you may want to give Lubuntu a try, which is the least demanding flavor of Ubuntu.

Kubuntu itself actually runs very well on this machine. Web browsers and electron-based apps like MS Teams and vscode, not so much... and a lightweight distro will not solve the heaviness of those apps unfortunately.

What thermal management program/daemon is running? is it thermald? check via systemctl status thermald. If yes, its operating parameters might just need to be adjusted. I prefer a lower than default trip point temperature and a very simple set of control parameters. See here.

see also here. What CPU frequency scaling driver are you using? Check by cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_driver. By default, and for your pre-HWP intel processor it should be intel_cpufreq.

@DougSmythies scaling driver is intel_cpufreq, and thermald is running. Though I do have some interesting logs. Please check my edit

I get those log entries also if I start thernald, well not the "does not exist" one because I use a /etc/thermald/thermal-conf.xml file so as to override the default. While working on your issue, I have discovered that thermald has what I believe to be an issue with intel_cpufreq. See here. However, the idle_inject method should be good enough, but what you need to do is set a lower than default temperature trip point.

Or just disable turbo boost: echo 1 | sudo tee /sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/no_turbo

As a first step, the program / process which causes the high CPU load should be identified. Open a terminal and run top. This will show all processes running, including their consumption of CPU time and RAM. In case the list is not sorted by CPU consumption, press the t key to sort accordingly. In case their is any process which can be safely killed consuming a lot of CPU time - do so and check for improvements.
As a second step, the settings of the Linux kernel for the CPU can be manually check. In the /sys pseudo filesystem is a directory for each CPU core which holds corresponding information. Switch to the directory for CPU0 (should be identical for all CPUs anyway) cd /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/ and check the file scaling_governor: cat scaling_governor. The output should be either "ondemand" or "intel_pstate". The supported governors for your CPU are listed in the file scaling_available_governors. You can manually set the scaling governor for each CPU core. The following command sets the "powersave" governor for the 1st CPU core (assuming it is supported for the given CPU):
echo powersave | sudo tee /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_governor

powersave means that the CPU core runs always on the lowest frequency, independent of the workload. This should prevent overheating the CPU, but may make the system unresponsive. Alternatively, convervative instead of powersave can be used to conservatively change to higher frequencies. A detailed description of the different scaling governors can be found in the Linux Kernel Documentation.
Please note that it is on regular functioning systems normally not necessary to change the scaling governor manually.
In the directory /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/ there will also be, depending on the CPU and its age, either a directory called stats or a number of directories named stateX, whereas X is a number, the lowest number is 0. The number represent the idle state ("C-state") of the CPU, so there is a directory for each idle state.
In case the stats directory exists, change into it and have a look into the file time_in_state: cat time_in_state. The file holds information on how many milliseconds the CPU core was running at which frequency.
In case the stateX directories exist, switch in the cpu0 one and check the file time: cat time. The file holds information for the given CPU core how many milliseconds the CPU core spent in this idle state. The state 0 is when the core is in full use, the higher numbers represent idle / sleep states. The higher the number, the higher / deeper the sleep state. Compare the output of time in the cpu0 directory to the values in higher idle states.
In case there is no process consuming a lot of CPU time and the CPU spents the majority of time in at a lower frequency and / or higher idle state but overheats anyway, there may be something wrong with the cooling system.

The culprit app right now is VSCode. CPU usage spikes whenever I type, not sure why. I don't think I have a solution for this except taking frequent breaks while programmign. However, there's nothing wrong with an app that uses 100% of your CPU. The scaling_governor is set to schedutil. Not sure what that means, but I switched it to "ondemand", let's see how that goes. Also, there's no stats or stateX in that directory. The CPU does scale in normal usage, it's not throttling its scaling when temperatures are high.

@9a3eedi CPU usage spiking when you type makes me think about autocompletion and suggestion tools.  I don't use vscode but you might want to try turning anything like that off, then turning back on the ones you find most helpful

If the main thermal control method is idle_inject then the CPU frequency doesn't scale down because thermal management is supposed to be achieved by the forced idle times. On my system the idle time data is in /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpuidle/state*/time for cpu0 and for example.

@ChrisH Autocompletion and suggestion tools are the reason I use vscode, otherwise I'd be using vim.

I've given ondemand a try. Maybe it's just me but I felt it did cool the laptop better, and I can tell that the cpu frequency was now more "nuanced"... but it still eventually overheated. Powersave would probably work as it keeps the clock at 1.2GHz, but this makes the computer a little too slow. So I'll give conservative a try. I think this is a great workaround, thanks @noisefloor

According to the specifications, Tjunction is 105°C.
The mobile i7 from that time will reduce the clock rate when they hit this number, not before. Mine does as well, and it's been running fine for over ten years.
If you get a system shutdown, then you run into a second limit after that, when reducing the clock rate does not help. This is an older machine, it will probably need new thermal paste or a replacement fan at some point (mine certainly did).
I'm using the ondemand governor, with
echo 1 >/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/ondemand/ignore_nice_load

so background processes don't cause a frequency switch, that also helps immensely if I don't need something right away, I can start it in the background with nice or batch.

I have one of these 3rd gen i7s with Windows and it was running at 95C with no throttling.  At idle it runs just over 60C.  I had just installed Coretemp over the weekend because the fan started out noisy and I wanted to ensure it was still cooling properly, so its all fresh in my head.

Yes, mine runs up to 105 with no throttling, then stays exactly there. Idle is about 45 for me, with no fan (I leave it on over night, never spins up). If you get 60 at idle, I suspect the thermal coupling to the heatsink is indeed not as good as it should be.

It's a laptop, I only power it on to use Quicken every few weeks.  Windows spends the first 5 minutes maxing the CPU at startup.

The thing is, I also monitor the clock rate of the CPU. It stays boosted at 3.5GHz with no signs of going down despite how high the temperatures are.. it's as if the CPU doesn't know how to throttle itself. Shouldn't the CPU only boost above its rated clock if temperatures and power allows for it?
Admittedly, the heatsink/fan/paste probably isn't in the best condition, but I was expecting some throttling to occur either way

@9a3eedthei correct, that's also my understanding that the CPU has some built-in protection that throttles once critical temperatures are reached. No matter what the workload is. Maybe there is a hardware error inside the CPU? The CPU is around 14 years old, so this may happen.
